# How to use "apoc.map.fromPairs" in Neo4j and APOC v3.4.0.1?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am new to neo4j and I am trying to play with it by trying to load an XML file into a map.

I tried the following example posted in [APOC User Guide](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_turn_pairs_into_map):

```
call apoc.load.xml("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.4/src/test/resources/xml/books.xml") yield value as catalog
UNWIND catalog._children as book
WITH book.id as id, [attr IN book._children WHERE attr._type IN ['author','title'] | [attr._type, attr._text]] as pairs
CALL apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs) yield value
RETURN id, value
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureNotFound: There is no procedure with the name `apoc.map.fromPairs` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed.
```

I read on the note that "apoc.map.fromPairs" is not a Procedure under "apoc-3.4.0.1" so I tried the following instead. So I tried to convert the statement to:

```
call apoc.load.xml("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.4/src/test/resources/xml/books.xml") yield value as catalog
UNWIND catalog._children as book
WITH book.id as id, [attr IN book._children WHERE attr._type IN ['author','title'] | [attr._type, attr._text]] as pairs
RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs)
```

Which did not work. I got the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'apoc.map.fromPairs' (line 4, column 8 (offset: 320))
"RETURN apoc.map.fromPairs(pairs)"
```

any thought on how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Neo4j and APOC are you using?

Comment: apoc-3.4.0.1 and Neo4j 3.4.4

Comment: Any news on that? I am facing the same problem ... mine is worst as RETURN works fine but not CALL